# Контекст не обновляет состояние после инициализации

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

**Суть проблемы**: Состояние (`state`) в App (см. код#1) не обновляется.

Функция `useParameter` - контекст (см. код#2) на хуке `ParameterHook` (см. код#3), у которого есть  State, который я и импортирую.

Подключение контекста происходит в `ContextContainer` (см. код#4) и проблема точно не в нём, остальные контексты работают.

**Причина некорректной работы**: Поверхностную причину я понимаю - `state` видимо инициализируется только после импорта, но при этом установка стандартного значения в `createContext` не спасает ситуацию.

Заранее благодарю за помощь <3

```
export const App = () => {
    const { isLoaded } = useParameter();

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <ContextContainer>
                <header>
                    <NavigationComponent/>
                </header>

                { !isLoaded ? <LoadingComponent/> : "" }
            </ContextContainer>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

```
const ParameterContext = createContext({ });

export const useParameter = () => {
    return useContext(ParameterContext);
}

export const ParameterProvider = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <ParameterContext.Provider value={{ ...ParameterHook() }}>
            { children }
        </ParameterContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

```
export const ParameterHook = () => {
    const [isLoaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

    return { isLoaded, setLoaded };
}
```

```
export default ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <ParameterProvider>
            <APIProvider>
                <AnimationProvider>
                    { children }
                </AnimationProvider>
            </APIProvider>
        </ParameterProvider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `App` является родителем `ContexProvider`, а должен быть потомком.

```js
const App = () => {
    const { isLoaded } = useParameter();

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            /*<ContextContainer> необходимо перенести на уровень выше*/
                <header>
                    <NavigationComponent/>
                </header>

                { !isLoaded ? <LoadingComponent/> : "" }
            /*</ContextContainer> необходимо перенести на уровень выше*/
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

/* Здесь App является потомком ContextContainer*/
const AppWithContext = () => (
  <ContextContainer>
    <App />
  </ContextContainer>
)
```